# how to install jenkins server on redhat

Tags: linux, jenkins, redhat

I goggled a lot for installing Jenkins server on red-hat Linux, but could not find proper source. does any body have idea

> how to install Jenkins server on red-hat

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Red+Hat+distributions

Answer (score 1):

finally i got a solution

```html
    sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
    sudo rpm --import https://jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key
    sudo yum install jenkins
```

[source to install jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins)